# I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will combine 2 WMI commands together

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem; -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName computer001, computer002 | Name, Caption, Identifyingnumber, vendor, UserName  Export-CSV ComputerList.csv
```

Is what I have so far.
I am trying to get this type of output

```
Model: OptiPlex 760                 
Name: Computer006
UserName: Domain\UserName
SerialNumber: M4RQFQZ
```

If it can be exported into excel with headers, that would be great too.  I have 10 remote stores I need to run this for.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one `Get-WmiObject`-call per WMI class and create a custom object with the combined data. Ex:

```
#$servers = "computer001", "computer002"
$servers = "localhost", "localhost" #test

$servers | ForEach-Object {
    $CS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_
    $BIOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_ 

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Model = $CS.Model
        Name = $CS.Name
        UserName = $CS.UserName
        SerialNumber = $BIOS.SerialNumber
    }
}

UserName       Name    Model               SerialNumber
--------       ----    -----               ------------
FRODEPC\Frode FRODEPC System Product Name System Serial Number
FRODEPC\Frode FRODEPC System Product Name System Serial Number
```

You could use pipe it through `Format-List Model, Name, UserName, SerialNumber` to get a list-view, but I won't work if you want to export it (to export, pipe it directly to `Export-CSV ...`)

```
Model        : System Product Name
Name         : FRODEPC
UserName     : FRODEPC\Frode
SerialNumber : System Serial Number

Model        : System Product Name
Name         : FRODEPC
UserName     : FRODEPC\Frode
SerialNumber : System Serial Number
```

As you can see I have a custom built computer, but it should display proper model and serialnumber values for a prebuilt OEM-machine.

Comment: The PowerShell Script works great !!! And I thank you.... I just cant get it to export to CSV.  I keep getting errors.


Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Char' required by parameter 'Delimiter'. Specified me
thod is not supported.
At line:11 char:11
+ Export-CSV <<<<  c:\CSVTest.csv $CS,$BIOS
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand


Any help with this would be fantastic !!
Thanks again !

Comment: You can't write `Export-CSV c:\CSVTest.csv $CS,$BIOS`. You could either pipe it directly to export-csv (random column order), by modifying the last line (`}`) to `} | Export-CSV -Path "c:\CSVTest.csv"` or specify the order by going through `Select-Object` like `} | Select-Object Model, Name, UserName, SerialNumber | Export-CSV -Path "c:\CSVTest.csv"`